# ¿Cómo puedo guardar la salida estándar en un fichero y los mensajes de error en otro?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, búsquedas

No logro que me guarde cada una de las salidas en los ficheros.

El siguiente comando UNIX busca nombres de ficheros y directorios a partir de un determinado directorio (en el caso del comando indicado el directorio raíz):

```
find / -name passwd -print
```

Como se puede ver al ejecutarlo se mezclan la salida estándar y la salida de error. El comando tarda bastante en finalizar, por lo que se puede abortar su ejecución pulsando `ctrl^C`.

Mediante el procedimiento adecuado, debo hacer que la salida estándar se almacene en el fichero `resultado_busqueda` y los mensajes de error que aparecen se añadan a los ya existentes en un fichero llamado errores. Debo ubicar ambos ficheros en mi HOME.

He probado `ls -l find / -name passwd -print > resultado_busqueda > error`  y me crea los ficheros pero vacíos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No te debería crear dos vacíos, únicamente el de `resultado_busqueda` ya que estás redireccionando finalmente la salida a `error`. Lo que debes hacer es agregar el 2 para redireccionar los errores a `error`, así:

```
find / -name passwd -print > resultado_busqueda 2> error
```

Answer (score 1):

Añade lo siguiente al final de tu comando:

```
find / -name passwd -print 2>&1 > ~/resultado_busqueda | tee -a ~/resultado_busqueda > ~/errores
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar lo siguiente, redireccionando los resultados sin usar `-print`:

```
find / -name passwd 2>fichero_errores.txt 1>resultados.txt
```

Explicación:

- 1 es la salida estándar.
- 2 es la salida de errores estándar.

Puedes una explicación más completa en [SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/818284/1919228)

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente lo que quieres hacer aquí es ejecutar un comando y guardar el resultado *normal* en un fichero y el resultado *erróneo* en otro. Que sea `find` es irrelevante aquí, pues aplica a cualquier comando.

- la salida *normal* se conoce como "stdout" (standard output, es decir, salida estándar). Es la que se produce cuando dices cosas como `echo "hola"`.
- la salida *errónea* se conoce como "stderr" (standard error, es decir, error estándar). Es la que se produce cuando dices cosas como `ls akjdfalksjd`, es decir, hacer `ls` a un archivo inexistente.

En Bash, los numerales `0` hasta `9` sirven de descriptores de ficheros y cada uno se asigna para alguna cosa:

- `0` es el `stdin` (standard input, es decir, entrada estándar).
- `1` es el `stdout` y es el que se usa por defecto.
- `2` es el `stderr`.

Y como todas las cosas en Bash, se pueden redirigir. Por tanto, es cuestión de decir cualquiera de estas dos cosas:

```
comando 1>fichero_stdout 2>fichero_stderr

comando >fichero_stdout 2>fichero_stderr # 1> y > son equivalentes
```

O, en tu caso particular:

```
find / -name passwd -print > fichero_stdout 2 > fichero_stderr
```